# Sumatoria de una categoria dentro de un data.frame

Tags: r

A partir de un data.frame con las siguientes caracteristicas:

```
df <- data.frame(mes= rep(10:12, each = 4)
                 , hour = rep(1:2, 6)
                 , value = sample(1:12))

df

> df
   mes hour value
1   10    1     6
2   10    2     9
3   10    1    10
4   10    2    12
5   11    1     7
6   11    2     2
7   11    1    11
8   11    2     3
9   12    1     5
10  12    2     1
11  12    1     8
12  12    2     4
```

me gustaria generar otro data.frame con las sumas acumuladas de "value" por hora en cada uno de los meses algo como esto:

```
>df2
   mes hour value
1   10    1    16
2   10    2    18
3   11    1    18
4   11    2     5
5   12    1    13
6   12    2     5
```

alguna idea de como puedo lograrlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para este tipo de situaciones la librería `dplyr` hace muy fácil la transformación que necesitas. Simplemente creas primero los grupos de datos (en este caso, cada combinación de mes y hour) y luego haces un sumario, en este caso con la sumatoria de `value` para cada uno de los grupos que definiste antes. Uso tuberías para enlazar las funciones, pero podrías formularlo de otro modo.

```
library(tidyverse)      #Esta librería a su vez empaqueta a `dplyr` y otras librerías muy útiles para manipulación de datos. 

tribble(
~mes, ~hour, ~value,
 10,    1,     6,
 10,    2,     9,
 10,    1,    10,
 10,    2,    12,
 11,    1,     7,
 11,    2,     2,
 11,    1,    11,
 11,    2,     3,
 12,    1,     5,
 12,    2,     1,
 12,    1,     8,
 12,    2,     4) ->datos     #Creo la estructura de datos y le asigno el nombre datos.
```

Con esto ya tengo en mi entorno el objeto datos.

```
datos %>%                      #La tubería pasa la función siguiente (lo llamamos lado derecho) el output de la anterior (lado izquierdo). En este caso pasa el objeto datos.  
group_by(mes, hour) %>%        #Agrupo por mes y hour, si miras el output de esta función verás que no cambia nada en los datos, pero agrega atributos de grupos que usará la siguiente función. 
  summarise(suma=sum(value))   #Crea un sumario con la sumatoria de datos, lo interesante es que la sumatoria es para cada uno de los grupos que definí antes.
```

y obtengo:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   mes [?]
mes  hour  suma
<dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
  10     1    16
  10     2    21
  11     1    18
  11     2     5
  12     1    13
  12     2     5
```

Después de la última función podrías usar el asignador a la derecha `->` para ponerle nombre a tu output, si es lo que necesitás. O usar el asignador tradicional `<-` al principio de toda la cadena. El resultado es el mismo: una `data.frame`. Eso es importante porque si quieres seguir haciendo operaciones tienes una estructura de datos muy manejable.

## Otros usos de `summarise()`

Con `group_by()` y `summarise()` es muy fácil hacer sumarios de los datos, siempre que tengan la estructura correcta. 
Por ejemplo, ver el promedio de value en cada mes:

```
datos %>% 
  group_by(mes) %>% 
  summarise(promedio=mean(value))
```

O identificar el valor mayor para un hour en cada mes:

```
datos %>% 
  group_by(mes, hour) %>% 
  summarise(maximo=max(value))
```

Comment: muchas gracias funciona

Answer (score 1):

Como alternativa a la buena respuesta de mpaladino, no puedo dejar pasar de señalar la solución usando **R base**:

```
aggregate(value~mes+hour, data=df, FUN=sum)
```

Explicación:

- [`aggregate()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html) es la función básica de R para armar grupos de un `data.frame` y aplicar múltipes rutinas a cada grupo
- Tiene muchas formas de ser invocada, esta, usando la fórmula `value~mes+hour` es óptima por que devuelve un `data.frame` similar al que buscas
- Sobre cada grupo aplicamos la función `sum()`

El único tema que le veo, es que la salida por defecto no tiene el orden que estarías esperando, pero eventualmente podríamos ordenar pasando la agrupación por un objeto intermedio, o incluso, más fácil, ajustar un poco la llamada a `aggregate()`:

```
> df
   mes hour value
1   10    1     8
2   10    2     5
3   10    1     4
4   10    2    11
5   11    1     2
6   11    2     3
7   11    1    12
8   11    2    10
9   12    1     6
10  12    2     7
11  12    1     9
12  12    2     1

> aggregate(value~hour+mes, data=df, FUN=sum)[,c(2,1,3)]
  mes hour value
1  10    1    12
2  10    2    16
3  11    1    14
4  11    2    13
5  12    1    15
6  12    2     8
```

Comment: muchas gracias me funcionó

Comment: Yo quiero hacer lo mismo, he probado tanto con el summarise como con aggregate y se me genera una lista de NA a pesar de que en los datos que uso para esto no tengo ningún perdido, ¿cómo lo arreglo?

Comment: @NoeliaMosPérez, no tengo forma de ayudarte sin conocer previamente que datos tienes, te sugiero que formules una pregunta y no olvides agregar un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y un ejemplo de la salida que buscas