# Crear promedio por subgrupos en R

Tags: r, while

```
ID -   Trial -   Tiempo
1   -   2      -    x2
1    -  3     -     x3  
1   -   4    -      x4 
1   -   5     -     x5 
1   -   6    -      x6  
1    -  7  -        x7
1   -   8       -   x8
1   -   9    -      x9
...  -  ...-
```

Tengo esta tabla con 23 diferentes ID, cada ID posee 90 trials y cada trials tiene un tiempo. Deseo crear una tabla que me indique el promedio por cada ID seccionado, que quede de la siguiente forma:

```
ID -   Promedio de trail 1-30 -   Promedio trial 31-60 - Promedio Trial 61-90 - prom 90 trials
1   -   
2    -   
3   -    
4   -    
5   -   
6    -  
7   -  
8   -   
...  -  ...-
```

Comment: Hola Ignacio está pregunta te podria ayudar. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/121667/sumatoria-de-una-categoria-dentro-de-un-data-frame?rq=1. Lo único que no me queda claro es que el 1-30, 31-60, 61-90 estos están dados por tiempo?  El tiempo 1 es x2, el 2 es x3... el 90 es x91? O están ordenados en la tabla?

Comment: O cuál seria la manera en la que identificas p.e. los trail 1-31?

Answer (score 1):

Si no entendí mal, tienes un `data.frame` similar a esto:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:23,each=90), 
                 Trial = rep(1:90,times=23),
                 Tiempo = runif(23*90))
```

Y lo que buscas es obtener el promedio de `Tiempo` por `ID` y por tres grupos definidos por un rango de `Trial`. Si puedes usar `tidyverse` es bastante sencillo resolverlo:

```
df %>% 
  # Generamos los grupos según intervalos
  mutate(grupo=c('1 a 30', '31 a 60', '61 a 90')[findInterval(df$Trial, c(0, 31, 61))]) %>% 
  # Agrupamos por estos grupos
  group_by(ID, grupo) %>% 
  # Obtenemos la media por cada grupo
  summarize(Promedio=mean(Tiempo)) %>% 
  # "Dispersamos" los promedios de cada grupo en columnas
  spread(grupo, Promedio) %>% 
  # Calculamos y agregamos el promedio Total por ID
  left_join(df %>% 
              group_by(ID) %>% 
              summarize(PromedioTotal=mean(Tiempo)))
```

Salida:

```
# A tibble: 23 x 5
# Groups:   ID [23]
      ID `1 a 30` `31 a 60` `61 a 90` PromedioTotal
   <int>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>
 1     1    0.461     0.559     0.510         0.510
 2     2    0.516     0.527     0.482         0.508
 3     3    0.498     0.470     0.507         0.492
 4     4    0.502     0.523     0.536         0.520
 5     5    0.495     0.543     0.479         0.506
 6     6    0.537     0.497     0.466         0.500
 7     7    0.489     0.518     0.474         0.494
 8     8    0.504     0.446     0.482         0.477
 9     9    0.468     0.467     0.492         0.476
10    10    0.594     0.484     0.497         0.525
# ... with 13 more rows
```